# Move Proc Tabulate Class Heading to Another Column

Tags: sas, proc

In my `Proc Tabulate` output, the class headings are above the `class` levels. Is there a way to move the class headings into a column of their own that sits next to the class levels? In the desired output in the image, the class heading of `'Education'` is in it's own cell next to the class levels. How can I accomplish this?

[Class Headings example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeuOT.png)

```
PROC FORMAT;
PICTURE PCTF (ROUND) OTHER='009.9%';
RUN;
ODS HTML PATH="%SYSFUNC(GETOPTION(WORK) )" STYLE=JOURNAL1A;
TITLE "Question 21x";
PROC TABULATE DATA = 208s;
CLASS EDUC 
      AREA
      AGE 
      SEX 
      CENRACE 
      POVERTY 
      EDUC 
      INSURE 
      HEALTH
      Q21x;
CLASSLEV EDUC AREA AGE SEX CENRACE POVERTY EDUC INSURE HEALTH Q21x ;

TABLE AREA    = 'Area in Region' * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      AGE     = 'Age'            * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.) 
      SEX                        * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      CENRACE = 'Race'           * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      POVERTY = 'Poverty Status' * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      EDUC                       * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      INSURE                     * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.) 
      HEALTH                     * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.) , Q21x = '   ';
RUN;
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the tabulate code to the question ? Is this question for the row dimension or the column dimension ?

Comment: The question is for adding a new column to the left of the class levels instead of one column with levels and headers.

Comment: Can you provide sample data or use a data set from SASHELP in your code instead and then we can test a solution?

Comment: Did you try adding a new variable with the text you want to appear?

Comment: I don't see an option to add sample data to the post.

Comment: @Tom - no, I don't want to add to my data unless I have to. This should be a simple table format issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose existing data into a categorical form, which will give you greater control over the row dimension layout.  Move the `ROWPCTN` into the column dimension to eliminate the blank column (in the row header) that would otherwise appear if `ROWPCTN` was in the row dimension. Use `NOCELLMERGE` to prevent merged cells in the first data row.

For example, start with

```
data have;
  do personid = 1 to 1000;
    area = cats('area_',0 + floor(5 * ranuni(123)));
    age  = cats('age_',13 + floor(7 * ranuni(123)));
    sex  = cats('sex_',1 + floor( 2 * ranuni(123)));
    q21x = byte(65+(5*ranuni(123)));
    output;
  end;  
  label area = 'Area Label';
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class area age sex q21x;
  table 
    ( area age sex ) * (rowpctn=' '), q21x
  / nocellmerge;
run;
```

[image: Proc TABULATE output]

And the transposed data version

```
proc transpose data=have out=have_for_table;
  by personid q21x notsorted;
  var area age sex;
run;

proc tabulate data=have_for_table missing;
  class _name_ _label_ col1 q21x;
  table 
    _name_='' * _label_='' * col1=''
    ,
    q21x * (rowpctn='')
    /
    nocellmerge
    ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It gets me closer, but I noticed in the output that the class levels of 'age', 'area', and 'sex' are numeric as a result of breaking away from the formats during the transpose operation. Any way to maintain that?

Comment: Format the variables first in the data set, or as a format statement in the TRANSPOSE step. The formatted values will end up in COL1